# how to retrieve user name from cookie session data(RAILS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, cookies, controller

I am studying ROR, I have some a partial side bar which gets rendered in the user dashboard area, and I am returning the user's name in the dashboard like so. originally the dashboard layout was included only in the user controller. but now i need to use it with a new controller

```
   <h1>Welcome Back,  <%= @user.name %> </h1>
```

so i changed it to

```
   <h1>Welcome Back,  <%= current_user %> </h1>
```

but the problem now is that instead of returning the Username, current_user returns this

```
   #<User:0x007fa8ee293940>
```

which I am assuming is the remember_token hash. Now since current_user already have the session cookie, I am not sure how I traverse the DB to get the the username. Can someone help me tweak current_user so it will get the current session user but returns the username?

thanks!

here is my session helper

```
    def sign_in(user)
        remember_token = User.new_remember_token
        cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
        user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.digest(remember_token))
        self.current_user = user
    end

    def current_user= (user)
        @current_user = user
    end

    def current_user
        remember_token = User.digest(cookies[:remember_token])
        @current_user || User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)       
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<User:0x007fa8ee293940>`
is a string representation of a User object. You want the name property of that object, similar to what you were doing before (@user.name). Instead of current_user, current_user.name should do it.